# Creating Custom FileField Datatype in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I want to create a custom `FileField` which can store multiple files in a single FileField and if possible I want to create a custom `upload_to` that can satisfy my need and there should not be any multiple entries for a single user in my database.

I have tried other approaches such as `Arrayfield` with `FileField` but they don't work together as it is a limitation in Django

What is  a good approach for this?

Comment: Why not create a model with a single FileField and create an instance for each file?

Comment: @GavinH I want to upload multi files in a form all together but when i upload them they create separate rows which will create a problem in a long run.